# Why does Django throw an exception whenever I enable admin.autodiscover()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dreamhost

Here is my setup. I am using Django version 1.1.1 on Dreamhost, Python 2.4. The problem I am having is whenever I create a simple app and also have admin.autodiscover() enabled, Django will throw an exception. My setup:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from testapp.views import HelloWorld

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^HelloWorld/$', HelloWorld),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My settings.py looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'testapp',
)
```

My testapp.views looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def HelloWorld(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

If I comment out admin.autodiscover() I can get to my view of HelloWorld. If I enable admin.autodiscover() Django throws an exception that I am not able to trap.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any info about the error at all? A printout/trace? Set debug=True in settings to make sure you get the error screen.

Comment: Could you add the exception message as well? You usually get pretty descriptive exceptions from Django (and Python in general).

Comment: I had endless inexplicable Django errors on dreamhost. I finally switched to webfaction which explicitly supports Django. What I don't remember about dreamhost is if you get log files? You got nothing, no tracebacks? On webfaction you get a log directory per app.

Comment: I do have debug=True but the problem is that the exception happens before Django can report it. Even if I setup Django to send emails on "500 Internal Server Error" it appears as though the exceptions happen before Django can even report it.

Comment: Can you show us your urls.py?

Comment: My urls.py is in the original post

Comment: Actually I think we need to see the testapp.admin file.

Comment: Because my view does not have a model how would I do a admin.site.register()?

Comment: Are you saying there's no admin.py within testapp? Well, at least one model does have an admin.py, and that's causing an error.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue when I've renamed an app. Basically, if you've launched the app and used the admin using `admin.autodiscover()` in your `urls.py` file, it will cause an `admin.pyc` file to be created in your app folder. Delete this `admin.pyc` file and run the server again...and voila!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that testapp/admin.py does not import the models.Model class you are creating admin for. Try the following:

```
./manage.py shell # you may immediately get a stack trace
>> import testapp.admin # I'll bet it blows up.
```

Comment: Yep - when I get try to import testapp.admin I get an ImportError exception

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still relevant. I had a similar problem that stumped me today. The issue was that I had refactored a set of files in a directory within a Django app folder (`lib/cache`) into a single file (`lib/cache.py`). Because there was still an `__init__.py` in the `cache` directory, Python was seeing the empty directory as a module and preventing access to `cache.py`.

Commenting out `admin.autodiscover()` in my `urls.py` made it a bit easier to track this down but it still took some guesswork.